# Floats not clearing properly causes elements to be hidden behind them

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I'm trying to get a paragraph (`<p>`) to be displayed after some content, but no matter what I do it's still hidden behind the previous element.

```css
.tabs input[type=radio] {
    display:none;
}
 
.tabs {
    width: 650px;
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px;
}
 
.tabs li{
    float: left;
}
 
.tabs label {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #2c3e50;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
 
.tabs label:hover {
    background: #3498db;
}
 
.tab-content {
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 140%;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 10px solid #08C;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

[id^=tab]:checked + label {
    background: #08C;
    color: white;
    top: 0;
}
 
[id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content] {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1">
        <label for="tab1">tab 1</label>
        <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
            <h3>Tab 1</h3>
            Some content.
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
        <label for="tab2">tab 2</label>
        <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
            <h3>Tab 2</h3>
            Some more content.
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3">
        <label for="tab3">tab 3</label>
        <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content">
            <h3>Tab 3</h3>
            Even more stuff.
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<br style="clear: both;" />

<p style="clear:both;">
Some other content
</p>
```

As you can see the `<p>` containing "Some other content" is hidden behind the tabs. I tried using `clear: both` but while it helped, the paragraph is still not coming *after* the tabs as I would expect. I want it to look like this:

[image]

An ugly fix is to limit the height of the tabs, use `overflow: auto` for the content within, and then set an enormous `margin-top` for the paragraph in question. But there's got to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: It's because you tab content div is positioned absolutely, so it's removed from the flow of the document.

Comment: When you say "after" the tabs, do you mean at the same height as the tabs and above the actual content of the tabs, or after the content of the tabs.

Comment: @MaximePeloquin After the content of the tabs, which could vary in height. See picture above

Comment: Ahh. I see that you don't want to use JS now. This would be really easy to do with a little JS, but pure CSS makes it a little tricky. Clever using radio inputs with labels, but why not just use JS?

Answer (score 0):

If this ul.tabs will have a fixed height you could do:

```
.tabs
    min-height: 190px
```

This will force height for the tabs container and push the p tag down.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you tab content - position: absolute

this variant may suit?

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tabs{
    max-width: 650px;
    margin: 20px;       
    font-size: 0;
}
.tabs input[type="radio"]{
    display: none;
}
.tabs label{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #2C3E50;
    color: #fff;    
    font-size: 24px;   
}
.tabs label:hover{   
    background: #4B6988;
}
.tabs label:active,
.tabs label:focus{   
    background: #0088CC;
}
.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label{
    display: inline-block; 
    background: #0088CC;
    color: #fff;
}
.tab-content{
    display: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'segoe ui';
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    position: relative;
}
.tab-content:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: -1px;
    width: calc(100% + 2px);
    height: 10px;
    background: #08C;    
}
.tab-content h3{
    font-size: 22px;
}
.tabs #tab1:checked ~ #tab-content1,
.tabs #tab2:checked ~ #tab-content2,
.tabs #tab3:checked ~ #tab-content3{     
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">    
    <input type="radio" id="tab1" name="tabs" checked />
    <label for="tab1">Tab 1 </label>
    
    <input type="radio" id="tab2" name="tabs" />
    <label for="tab2">Tab 2</label>
    
    <input type="radio" id="tab3" name="tabs" />
    <label for="tab3">Tab 3</label>
    
    <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content1">
        <h3>Tab 1</h3>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content2">
        <h3>Tab 2</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content3">
       <h3>Tab 3</h3>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    </div>   
</div>

<p>Some other content</p>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/o4e308du/)